# Extract OLE object containg images using VBscript

Tags: ms-access, object, ole

An OLE Object column contains images but the image type (jpg/gif/tiff) is unknown. These images need to be extracted from the DB and saved to disk using VBscirpt.

Comment: Have you tried the solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114326/converting-ms-access-ole-objects-back-to-plain-jpegs-best-way/114438#114438 ?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before in Delphi, the solution was to use the clipboard (somehow the clipboard can determine the type of image). Copy the contents of the field to the clipboard and then save the contents of the clipboard to a file.

Comment: Clipboard is a solution. More simple than Delphi is to add a form to MS ACCESS, place the image control and script the loop over all records with copying the image control content to clipboard

Answer (score 1):

OLE objects is bad way of storing images in MS Access. Use [OLEToDisk](http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm) to save your images as pic files.

After that reimport them in nice way. Check [AccessImagine](http://access.bukrek.net) for working with images in Access - it does all the hard job.

Comment: AccessImagine is a shareware, and the other one is not supported anymore, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found an example to take a screenshot with VBScript and paste it to MS Paint. Maybe you can modify it to do what you want?

http://hisudhakar.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!8DDF980C45482279!410.entry?sa=948299040