# Image.Save(..) throws a GDI+ exception with memory stream open

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm trying to extract the images from an MS Access database and saving them into a folder but am getting that error when saving the images.

I've checked other posts all around and issue usually is not using a memory stream or closing it before doing the saving or needing to create a new instance of the image because of it being used elsewhere. My issue has all that covered and still giving the error and the weirdest thing is that it works up to some point. The first 5 images are saved onto the folder but the 6th gives that error and if I jump the 6th the 7th is saved but the 8th gives that error again.

```
cmdIn.Connection = con;
cmdIn.CommandText = "SELECT [ID], [FOTO], [Designação Equipamento], [MARCA], [MODELO] FROM [Fotografias e Manuais de Equipamentos]";
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmdIn.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
     int id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);
     string nome="";
     if (rdr["Designação Equipamento"].ToString().Equals(""))
     {
         nome = "semNome";
     }
     else
     {
         nome = rdr["Designação Equipamento"].ToString();
     }

     string nomeImagem = id + "_" + rdr["MARCA"].ToString() + "_" + rdr["MODELO"].ToString() + "_" + nome;
     lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Processing ID {0}...", id);
     lblStatus.Refresh();
     byte[] b = (byte[])rdr["FOTO"];
     byte[] imageBytes = OleImageUnwrap.GetImageBytesFromOLEField(b, 1000000);
     using (MemoryStream msIn = new MemoryStream((byte[])rdr["FOTO"]))
     {
         Image img = Image.FromStream(msIn);
         // The error pops up here in the save
         img.Save(saveImagePath + nomeImagem + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
         //img.Dispose();
      }

}
```

I've tried with and without disposing the image, it makes no difference for the error.
If you want a sample of the said database [here](http://wikisend.com/download/363770/Bd%20Fotos%20Equipamentos%201.mdb) it is.

And here's the method GetImageBytesFromOLEField():

```
    public static byte[] GetImageBytesFromOLEField(byte[] oleFieldBytes, int NumMaximoBytesSearch)
    {
        //ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688641/convert-ole-object-in-datarow-into-byte-c-sharp
        // adapted from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranab/archive/2008/07/15/removing-ole-header-from-images-stored-in-ms-access-db-as-ole-object.aspx

        int MaxNumberOfBytesToSearch = NumMaximoBytesSearch;
        byte[] imageBytes;  // return value

        var ImageSignatures = new List<byte[]>();
        // JPG_ID_BLOCK = "\u00FF\u00D8\u00FF"
        ImageSignatures.Add(new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF });
        // PNG_ID_BLOCK = "\u0089PNG\r\n\u001a\n"
        ImageSignatures.Add(new byte[] { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A });
        // GIF_ID_BLOCK = "GIF8"
        ImageSignatures.Add(new byte[] { 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38 });
        // TIFF_ID_BLOCK = "II*\u0000"
        ImageSignatures.Add(new byte[] { 0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00 });
        // BITMAP_ID_BLOCK = "BM"
        ImageSignatures.Add(new byte[] { 0x42, 0x4D });

        int NumberOfBytesToSearch = (oleFieldBytes.Count() < MaxNumberOfBytesToSearch ? oleFieldBytes.Count() : MaxNumberOfBytesToSearch);
        var startingBytes = new byte[NumberOfBytesToSearch];
        Array.Copy(oleFieldBytes, startingBytes, NumberOfBytesToSearch);

        var positions = new List<int>();
        foreach (byte[] BlockSignature in ImageSignatures)
        {
            positions = IndexOfSequence(startingBytes, BlockSignature, 0);
            if (positions.Count > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        int iPos = -1;
        if (positions.Count > 0)
        {
            iPos = positions[0];
        }

        if (iPos == -1)
            throw new Exception("Unable to determine header size for the OLE Object");

        imageBytes = new byte[oleFieldBytes.LongLength - iPos];
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(oleFieldBytes, iPos, oleFieldBytes.Length - iPos);
        imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        ms.Dispose();
        return imageBytes;
    }
```

Note: This issue hasn't been solved yet.

Comment: That seems related to a specific image, or its image type. I remember I had similar problems dealing with GIF image format: maybe this is your case?

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas I know for sure they are all in PNG format.

Comment: Where do you dispose `OleDbDataReader rdr`? Or is it documented that it implements `IDisposable` for the hell of it? Repeat for `cmdIn` and `con`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [External Exception in GDI+ error saving specific image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095591/external-exception-in-gdi-error-saving-specific-image)

Comment: @HansPassant The code is much different and the issue Gord Thompson found was solved.

Comment: Everybody will assume there's something wrong with GetImageBytesFromOLEField() without having anything to look at.  You need to mark a post that solved your problem as an answer, you didn't.