# Extract Image from MSAccess OLE object using C#.NET

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

We have a legacy system in MSAccess which has a "OLE Object" Column to store images.
Now, we are trying to create a small executable to convert the "OLE object" back to image file using C#.
We came to know the users takes screenshot and paste dierctly to the MSAccess column.

But while retrieving data from access it returns the bytes but throws  **'Parameter is not valid.'** exception
while doing Image.FromStream(ms).

Here is my sample code.

```
//Connect to MSAccess database
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
try
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandText, conn))
  {
    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
      da.Fill(dt);
      if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
                                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                                {
                                    Byte[] imageBytes = dr[0] as Byte[];                                    
                                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
                                    Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                                    img.Save(destinationPath + "Image1.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
       finally
       {
         conn.Close();
       }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Access image OLE Object into raw image byte array in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688641/convert-access-image-ole-object-into-raw-image-byte-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The resolution suggested in the other links did not work. The end users took screenshot and pasted(Ctrl+V) in OLE object  column. So, it does not fall in any category like JPG, PNG etc.