# Image from MS Access in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, oledb

I'm currently working with MS Access and WPF with an OleDb. I then read the data using WPF using C#. Now I have entered images in Access as a field (attachment) and would like to display them in WPF. Work with an OleDbReader. Is there something like reader.GetImage(0)? Thanks in advance

SQL Syntax and maybe C# Code

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be, to get the image data as `byte[]` and bind it to an `Image.Source` in WPF.
[SqlReader.GetBytes@Learn.MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

in WPF/XAML

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageData, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

```cs
var length = (int) reader.GetBytes(columnIndexWhereTheImageDataIsStored,0,null,int.MaxValue);
var buffer = new byte[length];
reader.GetBytes(columnIndexWhereTheImageDataIsStored,0,buffer,0,buffer.Length);
```

Comment: Converting the field from an OLE object to a `byte[]` containing a valid image does not seem trivial, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19709053/2791540)

Comment: but at least there is already a solution for that [Convert Access image OLE Object into raw image byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688641/convert-access-image-ole-object-into-raw-image-byte-array-in-c-sharp)